# How to diagnose WCF Request errors if I don't have a "<behaviors>" node in my Web.Config?

Tags: wcf, web-config

Seeing the dreaded **Request Error** page while testing your WCF Web Service?

[image]

Well, worry not, because this StackOverflow answer shows you how to turn on detailed error display: [WCF Data Service - How To Diagnose Request Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313046/180430)

But ... *hang on*, we don't have a Web.Config that looks anything like that one.

Ours just has a `system.serviceModel` and that's it.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

*If* we go for it and simply add the following:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

on to the end, then boy is it unhappy:

[image]

### Update/Edit

Based on answers and comments from @burning_LEGION and @Chris (see below) I now have a `Web.Config` which looks like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
          <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior"></standardEndpoint>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
      </standardEndpoints>

      <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But I'm getting a Server Error:

> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'behaviorConfiguration'.
>   Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Chris and burning_Legion for pointing the way. This was the `system.serviceModel` which I eventually ended up with and which successfully shows the error detail.

It's per @burning_LEGION's answer but without the name attribute on the behavior:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
          <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
      </standardEndpoints>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Great - thanks for that, just putting it in the same behaviour with no name got me the error details too :)

Answer (score 3):

`behaviors` must be in tag `system.serviceModel`

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>   
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
           </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: thanks, so i've just done that. that *does* get rid of the Parser/Configuration error - so at least the web.config is valid again. but it's not like it's dispalying any exception details. I'm back to just the dreaded *Request Error* screen with no detail.

Comment: use behaviorConfiguration to identify the behavior to apply to your endpoint - so add behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior" (from the above example)

Comment: @Chris yep that's what i've got. the same 15 lines of XML that burning_Legion posted. but no exception detail, just _Request Error_

Comment: @hawbsl, Chris talk about replacing endpoin with this <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior"></standardEndpoint>

Comment: thanks, now i understand. and i've made that change. but it's still not happy. see my edit.

Comment: class `WebHttpEndpoint` have tag behavior, try use it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpendpoint.aspx

Comment: got a slightly different web.config to work and posted it as accepted answer. +1 and thanks to you guys.