# WCF DataService returns An error occurred while processing this request

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a strange promblem with DataServices when executing specific query:

`http://localhost:58362/DataService.svc/A?$expand=B/C` works as expected

`http://localhost:58362/DataService.svc/C?$expand=D` works as expected

On Query:

`http://localhost:58362/DataService.svc/A?$expand=B/C/D`
I get

```
{
    odata.error: {
        code: ""
        message: {
            lang: "en-EN"
            value: "An error occurred while processing this request."
        }
    }
}
```

No exceptions in visual. Just this result without more messages.

Can it be connected with amount of data?

Comment: Try to get more info about the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312894/wcf-data-service-how-to-diagnose-request-error?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved now.

There was `QueryInterceptor`, which filtered out some `C` models. That caused empty `C` property in some `B` elements in `http://localhost:58362/DataService.svc/A?$expand=B/C/D`. Trying expanding with `D` was breaking the result.

Solution is to prepare `QueryInterceptor`, which does not filter `C` models in some situations or prepare `QueryInterceptor` for `B`.